# Objects are not valid as a React child error when giving value to react-select

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-select

```
   **Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {label, value, __isNew__}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.**
```

getting this error when giving value prop to the component

this is the tags array i am getting from api
["apple","orange","banana"]

this is my code

```
                 <CreatableSelect
                        isMulti
                        name="tags"
                        value={values?.tags?.map((tag, index) => ({
                          value: tag,
                          label: tag,
                        }))}
                        defaultValue={values?.tags?.map((tag, index) => ({
                          value: tag,
                          label: tag,
                        }))}
                        getOptionValue={(option) => option.value}
                        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label}
                        onChange={(option) => {
                          setFieldValue("tags", option);
                        }}
                    />
```

Comment: you have to select multiple value right? I can see the isMulti attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the error it is telling Object is not valid child. And to use array instead. Currently you are just printing the whole object.

That's how you `onChange` method would look like:

```
onChange={(items) => {
  items.forEach((value) =>                                           
  setFieldValue("tags", ...value.value); 
  });
}}
```

You can change the code if some modifications are need as required. But that is the main idea that you have array so you will be showing multiple elements.